# Is there any way to limit user reply time in telebot?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I am writing bot, that asking some questions. My purpose is to give user specific amount of time for answer. If user doesn't answer in this time interval bot should skip question.

I tried to wait for answer in `while time.time() < end_time` loop but it didn't work.

Here is how i imagine it should look:

```
def ask_question():

    markup = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(one_time_keyboard=True)
    markup.add("yes", "no")
    msg = bot.send_message(user_id, "question", reply_markup=markup)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, wait_for_answer)

def wait_for_answer(message):

    chat_id = message.chat.id
    
    if message.text == "yes":
        #do something
    elif message.text == "no":
        #do something
    elif "not message.text after 3 minutes":
        #do something
```